# how to determine success string inline by using perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, cpu-word

hi i tried find $#lines include succcess  or not include in perl. But im sure $#lines include success but its returns not include. what is wrong with my code ?

```
if ( $#lines =~ /"success"/ ) {
print "Found success\n";
} else {
print "Did not find success\n";
```

Comment: If `@lines` is your array, wouldn't `$#lines` gives the length of the array? It wouldn't contain a string.

Comment: show some sample data so we can tell for sure what to recommend to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether some element of `@lines` array matches,

```
if (grep /"success"/, @lines) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
if ( $#lines =~ /"success"/ ) { ...
```

will always fail, since `$#lines` is the last index (zero-based) of `@lines`.  Thus, if `@lines` had 100 lines (indexes 0 through 99), your expression would effectively be:

```
if ( 99 =~ /"success"/ ) { ...
```

Use [mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec)'s solution.  However, if you're only looking for `success`, and the word's not enclosed by double-quotes, then use `/success/`.  And if you want a case-insensitive match, use the `i` modifier: `/success/i`.

Hope this helps!